# Adding a file that stores images temporarily to my S3 bucket from my django project

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-settings

#### Intro:

I have a Django web app that is hosted on AWS. Also, my static and media files are stored on AWS S3. I have 2 buckets in my S3 namely **Static** and **Media**. Everything was working fine. Now I wanted to add a JavaScript library that reduces images on the client side and uploads the images to my media folder. I was able to do this successfully in the development stage.

#### The catch:

The JavaScript library uses a folder(I have named the folder **filepond-temp-uploads**) where it saves the images temporarily while the user is filling the form and when the form is submitted it saves it in the **Media** folder and deletes it from the **filepond-temp-uploads** folder

This works perfectly in my development stage. Now in my production stage. The **Static** and **Media** folders are configured correctly in my S3 (*See code below*) I need to know how to add **filepond-temp-uploads** folder to my S3 in my Django Settings File

#### My Code:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.MediaStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'some_aws_busket_6d'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.StaticStorage'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_S3_DOMAIN = "%s.s3.amazonaws.com" % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/static/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/media/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

I have another file at my root level called **aws_storage_classes.py** Below is the code in that file

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = 'static'


class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = 'media'
```

Below is the code for my **filepond-temp-uploads** in my django settings

```
DJANGO_DRF_FILEPOND_UPLOAD_TMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'filepond-temp-uploads')

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'debug.log'), #This is a file created by the library. Should I add this to my S3?. I am not sure But If I can I would love to. 
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django_drf_filepond': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'ERROR', #'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}

TEMP_EXPIRE_MIN = 300
```

I can make a folder called **filepond-temp-uploads** in my S3 how do I link it in my django settings.

---

> I tried the below

Adding another folder called `filepond-temp-uploads` in my aws S3 along with `static` and `media` folders
Adding another class to my **aws_storage_classes.py** in my django project

from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

```
class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = 'static'


class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = 'media'


class FilepondStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = 'filepond-temp-uploads'
```

Then I changed my `settings.py` as below

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.MediaStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'some_aws_busket_6d'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.StaticStorage'
DJANGO_DRF_FILEPOND_UPLOAD_TMP = 'aws_storage_classes.FilepondStorage' #I added this
```

and commented out the below

```
#DJANGO_DRF_FILEPOND_UPLOAD_TMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'filepond-temp-uploads')
```

However this did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: You are using `filepond-temp-uploads` folder on the machine where the application is running? If yes then it should work the same way in aws ec2 instance too. What exact issue you are facing?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The issue is that it is not able to find **filepond-temp-uploads** folder as a result the images are not resized and not not uploaded.  I think it is looking for that folder on the aws side. If there were 10,000 concurrent users there would be a lot of temporary images  keeping that folder in the project might be expensive. I mean it is in the project as of right now and undetectable in production

Comment: In the code, You need to check if the folder exists or not and create it if does not exist. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it works in the development stage. But not in production. In development stage **filepond-temp-uploads** in in my project directory that it saves and deletes images from there. However in production. It is not using that folder so I thought I have to create one in the S3 bucket

Comment: @SamirTendulkar what did you end up doing, im having the same problem.